# How to check if an IHttpHandler is loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, global-asax

I have a `global.asax` and I would like to check in the `Application_Start` method if a `IHttpHandler` with a certain name is registered. How can I do this?

<sub>The handler can be declared in the apps own web.config or one of another virtual parent directories or the machine.config.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a public method to do what you're asking for.

I think the code you want is either HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetHandlerMapping(), .MapHttpHandler() or .MapIntegratedHttpHandler(), but they are private or internal methods. However, you should be able to use reflection to call them.

An alternative would be some trial-and-error type testing (try to request a target that should be routed to the expected handler, and see what happens in several place, such as in the MapRequestHandler event in an HttpModule -- but I think Application_Start is too early for that.

Comment: Yeah, it's the only way to fly. jep, just fire up a request to the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `web.config` file using [WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx) method.  Due to [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx) all these configuration sections which are added in machine.config are available to your web-app so you need to read local web.config.

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
HttpHandlersSection section = (HttpHandlersSection)config.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");

GridView1.DataSource = section.Handlers;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: The handler can be declared in the apps own web.config or one of another virtual parent directories or the machine.config.